# xorg.conf missing?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

im using the closed nvidia driver:
i think my xorg.config is missing:

ls in the directory /etc/X11 shows:

```
app-defaults             rgb.txt             Xreset      Xsession.d
cursors                  xinit               Xreset.d    Xsession.options
default-display-manager  xkb                 Xresources  xsm
fonts                    xorg.conf.failsafe  Xsession    Xwrapper.config
```

is this normal?
i would like to edit the file with this:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTY1OTM&page=news_item

"Option "Coolbits" "12""

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Current ubuntu distributions (i guess since 10.04) don't ship with an X config file any more.

If you even interested in having a xorg.conf, you can find [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) some useful help.

Comment: thank you, so creating: a test.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d and then writing Option "Coolbits" "12" should add this option? :)